# Sub-pixel rounding JavaScript/jQuery solution for IE8 for tablecells with percentual width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

So, apparently IE8 won't accept defaultView(and thus no getComputedStyle) like IE9+, FF and Webkit-browsers do, which makes things troublesome. After making sure the browser doesn't accept defaultView I rerender my table-cells' widths with the following function:

```
function redimTable() {
    var containerWidth = 0;
    var numPerc = 0;
    var correctionWidth = (((1/2) / parseFloat(document.getElementById('kw-table').offsetWidth)*100));

    $($('#kw-table th').get().reverse()).each(function(j,k){
        if($(k).hasClass('w-5')){
            $(k).attr('width','5%');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('w-10')){
            $(k).attr('width','10%');
        } else {
            $(k).removeAttr('width');
        }
    });

    $('#kw-table th').each(function(j,k){
        if($(k).attr('width')){
            containerWidth = parseFloat($(k).attr('width').replace('%','')) - correctionWidth;
            numPerc = numPerc + containerWidth;
            $(this).attr('width',containerWidth+'%');
        } else {
            numPerc = 100 - (numPerc);
            $(this).attr('width',numPerc+'%');
        }   
    });
}
```

So IE8 rounds "the right way" (sorry for the sloppy coding, by the way), according to http://tylertate.com/blog/2012/01/05/subpixel-rounding.html

However, the table-cells in my generated, fixed header still don't align with the table-cells of the actual table, structured like so:

```
<table class="data-table" id="kw-table">

  <thead class="data-header">
  <tr class="labels-row">
    <th class="th0 w-a"><div class="a-l"><a href="">Keyword</a></div></th>
    <th class="th1 w-10"><div class="a-l"><a href="">Campaign</a></div></th>
    <th class="th2 w-10"><div class="a-l"><a href="">Ad group</a></div></th>
    <th class="th3 w-10"><div class="a-l"><a href="">Network</a></div></th>
    <th class="th4 w-10"><div class="a-r"><a href="">Clicks</a></div></th>
    <th class="th5 w-10"><div class="a-r"><a href="">Impr.</a></div></th>
    <th class="th6 w-5"><div class="a-r"><a href="">Avg. pos.</a></div></th>
    <th class="th7 w-10"><div class="a-r"><a href="">Status</a></div></th>
    <th class="th8 w-10"><div class="a-r"><a href="">Costs</a></div></th>
    <th class="th9 w-5"><div class="a-r"><a href="">Conv.</a></div></th>
    <th class="th10 w-5"><div class="a-r"><a href="">Est. bid first page</a></div></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot class="data-footer">
  <tr class="sum-row">
    <td class="a-l">Total</td>
    <td class="a-l">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="a-l">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="a-l">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="a-r">100.000</td>
    <td class="a-r">1.231.234.456</td>
    <td class="a-r">0,7</td>
    <td class="a-r">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="a-r fin">&euro; 12.211.878,38</td>
    <td class="a-r">2.000</td>
    <td class="a-r fin">&euro; 0,30</td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody class="data-body">
  <tr class="data-row first-row">
    <td class="a-l">Keyword</td>
    <td class="a-l"><a href="">Campaign</a></td>
    <td class="a-l"><a href="">Ad group</a></td>
    <td class="a-l">Search</td>
    <td class="a-r">49</td>
    <td class="a-r">4.116.017</td>
    <td class="a-r">3,6</td>
    <td class="a-r">enabled</td>
    <td class="a-r fin">&euro; 8,38</td>
    <td class="a-r">0</td>
    <td class="a-r fin last-cell">&euro; 0,30</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
.data-table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  empty-cells:show;
  line-height:1;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
  table-layout:fixed;
  overflow:visible;
  z-index:8;
}
.data-table th, .data-table td {
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-size:0.75em;
  line-height:1.5em;
  padding:.5em .6em;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}

.cloned-table {
  background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA9JREFUeNpiYGBgkAcIMAAAJAAgtVWAKwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
  margin-left:0;
  padding-bottom:4px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:9;
}
.cloned-table.fixed {
  position:fixed;
}

.a-l {text-align:left;}
.a-r {text-align:right !important;}
.fin {white-space:nowrap;}

th.w-5 {width:5%;}
th.w-10 {width:10%;}
```

What I'm looking for is someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisited this and figured it out:

cWidth = elem.getBoundingClientRect().right-elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;

Solves it. No need for computedStyle shenanigans, etc.